How to make children expand vertically in column without specifying the height
I want to have a series of buttons like in the attached image.

Below is my code, but the various buttons are not close together.
I tried wrapping each button in an Expanded widget, but this gives the error:

RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

because the height is missing.
Wrapping everything in a Container with height works, but I don't want to specify the height because I need to use multiple widget like this, with a variable number of buttons.
How do I solve it?
Thanks in advance!
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FilledButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      iconAlignment: IconAlignment.end,
      label: const Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text("Item A"),
      ),
      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(12)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const Divider(height: 0, indent: 0, thickness: 1),
    FilledButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      iconAlignment: IconAlignment.end,
      label: const Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text("Item B"),
      ),
      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const Divider(height: 0, indent: 0, thickness: 1),
    FilledButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      iconAlignment: IconAlignment.end,
      label: const Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text("Item C"),
      ),
      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(12)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),


Try to give mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, to main Column.

@DroidFlutter this doesn't bring the widgets closer together, it just makes the space equal

Add a Spacer() as last widget in the column?

Isn't that extra space from the FilledButton itself? You can try messing around with these ButtonStyle properties: visualDensity, padding, tapTargetSize.

Running your code in Dart Pad does actually render the buttons close together which means that the problem might be higher in your widget tree. It seems that the Column does not have height constraints so I assume it's in a scroll view. You can try to set its mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and see if that works.

@Dhafin Rayhan thank you so much! tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap solved my problem!

To solve this issue, you need the following property in each button:
style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  ...
),

